# Midnight commander not running

Tags: freebsd, mc

I have installing Midnight commander from FreeBSD 12.0-current with:

```
pkg install mc
```

When calling `mc` as as root, it runs as supposed; however when running as a normal user, it aborts with the error:

```
common.c: unimplemented subshell type 1
read (subshell_pty...): No error: 0 (0)
```

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/55627/), there is a bug/problem with mc, depending also on how it is compiled.

The option is to recompile it with `SUBSHELL` off; or to run it as:

```
mc -u
```

So, the easiest option is to create an alias to `mc` as `mc -u`. As in:

```
alias mc='mc -u'
```

From `man mc`:

> -u, --nosubshell
>                 Disable  use  of  the concurrent shell (only makes sense if Midnight Commander has been built with concurrent shell support).

Answer (score -1):

This error appears also, if you change default root shell to /bin/sh. There is information in package that subshell works almost everywhere excluding /bin/sh. Change default shell to /bin/csh and should be ok:

```
pw user mod root -s /bin/csh
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).